# STM32 cubeIDE incomplete build

Tags: stm32cubeide

I am trying to build C program for stm32 blue pill board for a led blink project using STM32cube IDE on a linux host.

When I build the project I am getting console output as below

```
 01:31:48 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project interface ****
    make -j4 all 
    arm-none-eabi-size   interface.elf 
       text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
       4720      20    1572    6312    18a8 interface.elf
    Finished building: default.size.stdout
     

01:31:48 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 97ms)
```

But the training video provides extensive lines on pressing build button in the console window.

Can I know what is wrong with the settings of Cube IDE?

Answer (score 0):

> But the training video provides extensive lines on pressing build
> button in the console window.

The training video is rubbish. There are no buttons in the console window.

> Can I know what is wrong with the settings of Cube IDE?

Nothing, simply your video is wrong and misleading

> When I build the project I am getting console output as below

It is 100% correct build. Now you are ready to flash your board.